# Unable to hit shopify requests from ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, shopify, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Everything was working fine till yesterday/today midnight. But today we are unable to access shopify REST apis from our ec2 instance located in Bombay (ap-south-1). The dns resolves correctly to the shopify shop:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-194 ~]$ dig turms.myshopify.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.68.rc1.58.amzn1 <<>> turms.myshopify.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52296
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;turms.myshopify.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
turms.myshopify.com.    30  IN  CNAME   shops.myshopify.com.
shops.myshopify.com.    8   IN  A   23.227.63.64

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 172.31.0.2#53(172.31.0.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Jun  1 06:13:17 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

Hitting the shop for any REST apis doesn't work:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-194 ~]$ curl -vX GET   https://turms.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-04/orders/metafieldId/metafields.json   -H 'Accept: */*'   -H 'Authorization: Basic Auth'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 23.227.63.64...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 23.227.63.64 port 443 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to turms.myshopify.com port 443: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to turms.myshopify.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Why are shopify calls failing from inside the ec2 instance? Restarting the server, flushing cache and bringing up a new machine have give me no results so far. Any help is appreciated.

Update:
This issue is not there in us-east instances. So we created a proxy instance to route shopify calls from our app through the proxy server. This is not a long term solution and we are still looking for answers.

Comment: It might be that Shopify is blocking the range of IP addresses to prevent scraping. You'll need to ask Shopify.

Comment: I asked shopify, they said that it was an aws issue and some other clients also had the same problem. They could not give a solution though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the issue was but here is the official communication from Shopify:

> This is to let you know that early morning today there was a connectivity issue across Shopify's platform and this email is to inform you that your stores have been recovered, we understand that situations like this impact you, your business and your teams. The internet-wide network outage affected several services, including Shopify. Once the network has resorted please know our team worked to get your store online as soon as possible. In the coming days, we will work to fully understand how this widespread Internet infrastructure failure affected our platform.